# Order results by rank and value

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I have the following query which looks the most used applications and then make a rank of 15 with more consumption and then order them by it.

```
SELECT app, 
   srcip, 
   bandwidth 
FROM   ( 
            SELECT   app,srcip,bandwidth, 
                     rank() OVER (partition BY app ORDER BY bandwidth DESC)  AS xRank
            FROM     ( 
                              SELECT   app, 
                                       srcip, 
                                       Sum(COALESCE(sentbyte, 0)+COALESCE(rcvdbyte, 0)) AS bandwidth
                              FROM     $log 
                              WHERE    $filter 
                              AND      Logid_to_int(logid) NOT IN (4, 
                                                                   7, 
                                                                   14) 
                              GROUP BY app, 
                                       srcip 
                              HAVING   Sum(COALESCE(sentbyte, 0)+COALESCE(rcvdbyte, 0))>0
                              ORDER BY bandwidth DESC) dat) sub
WHERE  xRank < 15
```

This query gets the data that i need but not in the correct order. Here is an example of what i get.

```
app         srcip           bandwidth
0/0/icmp    132.245.18.194  1,080
0/0/icmp    40.96.0.98      840
0/0/icmp    40.96.0.114     600
0/0/icmp    132.245.13.210  360
```

However, the applications that used the most are others.

```
app                 srcip           bandwidth
HTTP.BROWSER_Chrome 192.168.1.241   582,191,297
HTTP.BROWSER_Chrome 192.168.1.16    495,352,897
MS.Windows.Update   192.168.1.125   415,221,314
POP3                192.168.1.160   109,979,690
HTTPS.BROWSER       192.168.1.240   96,237,582
```

I would like to first order by the applications that used most bandwidth and then make the rank of 15 of those. Here is an example but only with 3 ranked.

```
app                 srcip           bandwidth
HTTP.BROWSER_Chrome 192.168.1.241   582,191,297
HTTP.BROWSER_Chrome 192.168.1.16    495,352,897
HTTP.BROWSER_Chrome 192.168.1.16    89,369,142
MS.Windows.Update   192.168.1.125   415,221,314
MS.Windows.Update   192.168.1.160   109,979,690
MS.Windows.Update   192.168.1.240   96,237,582
```

I have tried putting ORDER BY bandwidth, xRank in the subquery but it didn't work properly. Thanks for the help in advance.

**Update:** I tested @GorgonLinoff answer and i got the same result as the 1st posted but if i add `DESC` I get the following. It is now being ordered properly by the most used app but the bandwidth order of the ranks in each is still disordered.

```
app                 srcip           bandwidth
HTTP.BROWSER_Chrome 192.168.1.241   582,191,297
HTTP.BROWSER_Chrome 192.168.1.101   89,369,142
HTTP.BROWSER_Chrome 192.168.1.16    495,352,897
HTTPS.BROWSER       192.168.1.12    69,579,488
HTTPS.BROWSER       192.168.1.240   96,237,582
HTTPS.BROWSER       192.168.1.241   84,061,350
```

Comment: How about `order by bandwidth` in the outer query?

Comment: If you mean to add it next `where xRank < 15` I get the second result I added on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want someting like this . . . the top three for each app, with the apps ordered by the total app bandwidth:

```
SELECT app, srcip, bandwidth 
FROM (SELECT app, srcip, 
             Sum(COALESCE(sentbyte, 0)+COALESCE(rcvdbyte, 0)) AS bandwidth,
             row_number() over (partition by app order by Sum(COALESCE(sentbyte, 0)+COALESCE(rcvdbyte, 0)) desc
                               ) as xrank,
             sum(Sum(COALESCE(sentbyte, 0)+COALESCE(rcvdbyte, 0))) over (partition by app) as appbandwidth
      FROM $log 
      WHERE $filter AND logid_to_int(logid) NOT IN (4, 7, 14)
      GROUP BY app, srcip 
      HAVING Sum(COALESCE(sentbyte, 0)+COALESCE(rcvdbyte, 0)) > 0
     ) s
WHERE xrank <= 3
order by appbandwidth;
```

Comment: I think I better add the result to my question... I can't format it properly on the answers.